# Cannot Keep OpenSSH Server Alive, Kill -15 and Deactivated using Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Desktop LTS

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I have a local network on my desktop running `openssh-server` using `Ubuntu 22.04.1 Desktop LTS`. I can not keep the SSH server alive no matter what I try.

The logs say there is a `kill -15` signal, which then makes the `Open SSH` server inactive. This happens either after I exit a remote connection or don't use it for a short period.

I can connect perfectly fine, I just cant keep the desktop server up.

```bash
sudo apt install openssh-server
sudo systemctl enable ssh
sudo service ssh restart
sudo service ssh status # active
```

It works sometimes, then it's `inactive` with the log message of:

```
ssh.service deactivated successfully.
```

Why is it de-activating after one client logs in or out? It's not 100% guaranteed to close immediately after this.

I can get it working perfectly fine again with `sudo service ssh restart`.

In the **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** the server only a few things I've tried, one being this which doesn't seem to matter:

```
ClientAliveInterval 600
```

I previously had this common error *(No longer though)* `Missing privilege separation directory: /run/sshd` so I added this to **/etc/rc.local**:

```bash
mkdir -p /run/sshd
```

I also found this snippet on here and added it to **/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/sshd.conf**

```bash
d /run/sshd 0755 root root
```

Then, I read somewhere that there s a bug with the `sshd.socket` *(I lost the source, sorry)*, so I masked it and everything seems to work the same if not better (besides the service ending).

```bash
systemctl mask sshd.socket
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I have done this with a clean install, tried with 2 Laptops and 1 Desktop all on Ubuntu 22 LTS, they all have the same problem keeping the SSH Server alive.

Im just trying to connect to different computers locally.

Comment: There is an Ubuntu Core 22 for IoT, There is an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop. There is an Ubuntu 22.04 Server. There are no Ubuntu 22 LTS. Please use the full version number in the YY:MM format.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS for Desktop (Jammy) `core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch`, I hope that is useful.